# Interact with swap function for Sushiswap contract

Tags: web3.py, sushiswap

I want to test swapping some ETH for DPX like so:
https://app.sushi.com/swap?inputCurrency=ETH&outputCurrency=0x6C2C06790b3E3E3c38e12Ee22F8183b37a13EE55&chainId=42161
However, when looking at the parameters needed to call the swap() function using Web3.py it's not clear what needs to be passed.
https://arbiscan.io/address/0x0C1Cf6883efA1B496B01f654E247B9b419873054#writeContract

i.e

1. amount0Out
2. amount1Out
3. to
4. data

I'm especially confused about the data parameter

Comment: Did you try passing it simply `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address you provided is the DPX LP Address, not the Swap Router.

According to Sushiswap documents, SushiSwapRouter address is: `0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F`

You can read more here: https://dev.sushi.com/docs/Developers/Deployment%20Addresses

Before we go try swapping with Web3.py, we have to know how it works.

**Always do tests on Testnet before to avoid money loss.**

---

## How to do Swap from ETH for Tokens directly in Sushiswap Router:

We can easily do a swap from here just connecting the wallet you want: https://etherscan.io/address/0xd9e1ce17f2641f24ae83637ab66a2cca9c378b9f#writeContract

[image: Swap Parameters]

Which parameter is:

1. payableAmount: Amount you want to spend in Ether value.
2. amountOutMin: Basically is the slippage, set 0 if you want 100% slippage.
3. path: Path of **WETH address,Token address** (Yes, for ETH -> Token swap it has to be in this sequence) separated with "**,**". For example: `0x00000000,0x11111111`
4. to: Your Wallet Address
5. deadline: Just use the current block timestamp + 60. (https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)

**This is how to swap ETH -> Tokens.**

**The "Swap From Tokens to ETH" will be a different function.**

Once we know how it works, it's easy to do a swap using Web3.py

---

## How to do Swap from ETH for Tokens with Web3.py

I'm doing this at BSC Testnet, but you can easily adapt this to Ethereum by just changing addresses and swap info at `__init__`.

```
import time
from web3 import Web3

class swapExample():
    def __init__(self):

        #Setup Wallet Informations and RPC
        #Usually we place these info in separate .env or .py or .json file.
        self.wallet = "" #your wallet address
        self.pk = "" #your wallet private key
        self.rpc = "" #your node or use public rpc
        self.web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(self.rpc)) #connect to web3

        #Setup Swap Value / Gas limit / Gwei
        #Change these values if you want.
        self.buy_amount = 0.01 #Ether value to spend
        self.gas = 500000 #gas limit
        self.gwei = 10 #gwei

        #Setup WETH token address (to spend) and Token address (to buy)
        #In my case I'll use WBNB to buy Safemoon token (at BSC Testnet)
        self.WETH = self.web3.toChecksumAddress("0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd")
        self.token_to_buy = self.web3.toChecksumAddress("0xdacbdecc2992a63390d108e8507b98c7e2b5584a")

        #Setup router address (Sushiswap Router Address)
        #In my case I'll use Pancakeswap Router (at BSC Testnet)
        self.router = self.web3.toChecksumAddress("0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3")

        #Setup SwapExactETHforTokens ABI
        #You can get this ABI directly from Verified Contract Source Code at Etherscan
        self.abi = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amountOutMin","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address[]","name":"path","type":"address[]"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"deadline","type":"uint256"}],"name":"swapExactETHForTokens","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"amounts","type":"uint256[]"}],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"}]

        #Creating instance.
        #We can call contract functions with this.
        self.router_contract = self.web3.eth.contract(address=self.router, abi=self.abi)

        #Do swap.
        self.swap()


    #From here we are going to create Swap function.
    def swap(self):
        #building transaction with swap parameters
        #you can edit this if you want
        swap_txn = self.router_contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
            0, #amountOutMin(slippage)
            [self.WETH,self.token_to_buy], #path (WETH,TOKEN)
            self.wallet, #to (your wallet)
            (int(time.time()) + 10000) #Deadline
        ).buildTransaction({
            'from': self.wallet,
            'value': self.web3.toWei(self.buy_amount,'ether'),
            'gas': self.gas,
            'gasPrice': self.web3.toWei(self.gwei,'gwei'),
            'nonce': self.web3.eth.getTransactionCount(self.wallet),
        })

        #Sign swap tx and send to blockchain
        sign_tx = self.web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(swap_txn, private_key=self.pk)
        buy_tx = self.web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(sign_tx.rawTransaction)
        print("Txn sent, awaiting for response.")
    
        #Await for result
        tx_result = self.web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(buy_tx) 

        # Transaction status verification
        # If status == 1: Swap success.
        if tx_result['status'] == 1: 
            print("Success! TX:", self.web3.toHex(buy_tx))
            return True 
        else: 
            print("Error! TX:", self.web3.toHex(buy_tx))
            return False


swapExample()
```

Output:

[image: Python Output]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be found here https://dev.sushi.com/docs/Products/V3%20AMM/Periphery/Deployment%20Addresses.

But does anyone know which adress we need?
Another user posted 0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F but i cant find this address on https://dev.sushi.com/docs/Products/V3%20AMM/Periphery/Deployment%20Addresses.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/97351)